# Determine the existence of a relation

Tags: combinatorics

I came up with the following relation:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j} \binom {\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j}i = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{p_i} \binom {p_i}{j} $$

where $p_i$ is an element of a set of $n$ positive integers.

It is probably a known relation yet I am still interested as to the approach one should take to determine the existence of a relation?

Answer (score 3):

> We  can show equality as follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j} \binom {\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j}i
> =2^{\sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j}
> =\prod_{i=1}^{n} 2^{p_i}
> =\prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{p_i} \binom {p_i}{j}
> \end{align*}

Here we apply the binomial identity $\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}=(1+1)^n=2^n$ twice.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Markus :)

Comment: @LukeTaylor: You're welcome! :-)